# Error while importing VGG16 h5 file ValueError: No model found in config file

Tags: python, keras, import

I tried to import vgg16 which I downloaded from google storage

```
    import keras
    import cv2
    from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
```

But I got that error

```
ValueError: No model found in config file.
```

[image]

Comment: please try entering full path either absolute or relative instead of just the file name in load_model.

Comment: you mean like adding / before it?

Comment: did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recreate the issue using your code and downloaded weights file mentioned by you. I am not sure about the reason for the issue but I can offer an alternative way for you to use pretrained vgg16 model from keras.

You need to use model from keras.applications file

Here is the link for your reference https://keras.io/api/applications/

There are three ways to instantiate this model by using weights argument which takes any of following three values None/'imagenet'/filepathToWeightsFile.
Since you have already downloaded the weights , I suggest that you use the filepath option like the below code but for first time usage I will suggest to use imagenet (option 3). It will download the weight file which can be saved and reused later.

You need to add the following lines of code.

Option 1:

```
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    model = VGG16(weights = 'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
```

Option 2:

```
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    model = VGG16(weights = None)
    model.load_weights('vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
```

Option 3: for using pretrained imagenet weights

```
   from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
   model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet')
```

The constructor also takes other arguments like include_top etc which can be added as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to load a model that is not a model and probably are just weights: so the problem is not in the load of the model but in the save.

When you are saving the model try:

1. If you are using callbacks then  `"save_weights_only"=False`
2. Else use the function `tf.keras.models.save_model(model,filepath)`

Answer (score 1):

A complete model has two parts: model architecture and weights.
So if we just have weights, we must first load architecture(may be use python file or keras file ), and then load weights on the architecture.
for example:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("facenet_keras.h5")
model.load_weights("facenet_keras_weights.h5")
```